# Adding Options to Select form-control in a custom dialog with bootbox.js in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootbox

currently I'm trying to display a dialog where you can delete a "shelf" when you click on a button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="deleteButton">Delete</button>
```

On the bootbox.js [example page](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html/) they link to [this file](https://gist.github.com/nahakiole/42f66c9ca7af4b528b4f#file-bb-html-form-js/) as a example.

This code works for me, except I don't know how to dynamically add the options from my ASP.NET MVC Model.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#deleteButton').click(function () {
            bootbox.dialog({
                title: "Delete Shelf.",
                message: '<div class="row">  ' +
                    '<div class="col-md-12"> ' +
                    '<form class="form-horizontal"> ' +
                    '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                    '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="shelfSelection">Shelf</label> ' +
                    '<div class="col-md-4"> ' +
                    '<select id="shelfSelection" id="shelfSelection" class="form-control">' +
                        '<option value="one">One</option>  <option value="two">Two</option><option value="three">Three</option> ' +
                        '</select> ' +
                        '<span class="help-block">Select the shelf to delete.</span> </div> ' +
                        '</div> ' +
                        '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                        '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="awesomeness">Confirmation</label> ' +
                        '<div class="col-md-4"> <div class="checkbox"> <label for="deleteConfirmation"> ' +
                        '<input type="checkbox" name="deleteConfirmation" id="deleteConfirmation"> ' +
                        'I confirm the deletion of the selected shelf.</label> ' +
                        '</div></div> </div>' +
                        '</form> </div>  </div>',
                buttons: {
                    cancel: {
                        label: "Cancel",
                        className: "btn-default",
                    },
                    success: {
                        label: "Delete",
                        className: "btn-danger",
                        callback: function () {
                            var name = $('#name').val();
                            var answer = $("input[name='deleteConfirmation']:checked").val()
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The Shelves are stored in a Collection:

```
@foreach (Shelf shelf in Model.Shelves)
{
    string shelfName = @shelf.Name;
}
```

Now my Question: How can I add the Shelves as "option" to the "select" element?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved it, I used a StringBuilder to create the message.

```
@{
string deleteFormString = string.Empty;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append(@"<div class=""row"">");
builder.Append("<div class=\"col-md-12\">");
builder.Append("<form class=\"form-horizontal\">");
builder.Append("<div class=\"form-group\">");
builder.Append("<label class=\"col-md-4 control-label\" for=\"shelfSelection\">Shelf</label>");
builder.Append("<div class=\"col-md-4\">");
builder.Append("<select id=\"shelfSelection\" id=\"shelfSelection\" class=\"form-control\">");
foreach (Shelf shelf in Model.Shelves)
{
    string optionString = string.Format("<option value=\"{0}\">{0}</option>", shelf.Name);
    builder.Append(optionString);
}
builder.Append("</select><span class=\"help-block\">Select the shelf to delete.</span> </div></div>");
builder.Append("<div class=\"form-group\">");
builder.Append("<label class=\"col-md-4 control-label\" for=\"deleteConfirmation\">Confirmation</label>");
builder.Append("<div class=\"col-md-4\"> <div class=\"checkbox\"> <label for=\"deleteConfirmation\">");
builder.Append("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"deleteConfirmation\" id=\"deleteConfirmation\">");
builder.Append("I confirm the deletion of the selected shelf.</label>");
builder.Append("</div></div> </div>");
builder.Append("</form> </div>  </div>");
deleteFormString = builder.ToString();
}
```

I used @Html.Raw(@deleteFormString) to add the string to the script.

```
$('#deleteButton').click(function () {
            bootbox.dialog({
                title: "Delete Shelf.",
                message: '@Html.Raw(@deleteFormString)',
                buttons: {
                    cancel: {
                        label: "Cancel",
                        className: "btn-default",
                    },
                    success: {
                        label: "Delete",
                        className: "btn-danger",
                        callback: function () {
                            var name = $('#name').val();
                            var answer = $("input[name='deleteConfirmation']:checked").val()
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```